# Flipping a Delphi panel

Tags: delphi, components, panel, flip, skew

I would like to give the user the experience that a panel with controls flips and another panel with controls comes up. An example of a window that flips is shown here: http://videos.videopress.com/16PTIkFa/flippin-modal-windows-small.mp4.
This is what I want inside a form. In metro style applications flipping tiles are more common, but I haven't found a solution for a panel with controls within a form.

Suggestions and examples are appreciated.

Comment: You might try to take a *screenshot* of the panel with the *old* child controls, hide them (or destroy if you want), reparent the *new* ones, hide them, and in the overriden `Paint` method play the flip animation from those *screenshots*. And finally show the just hidden *new* controls.

Comment: Which framework are you using?